# Show float result more readable in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this query:

```
select a.Nm,sum(NoInvoAb * CstPr) as 'kostnadRadLev_intäckt'
from dbo.ProdTr pt
inner join dbo.Actor a on a.CustNo = pt.CustNo
where a.CustNo > 0 and pt.TrDt like '2012%'
group by a.Nm
```

First row of the result:

> Cykelmagasinet AB  27865867.000000

But, I would like to change the format of the float number to something that´s easier to read like: 27 865 867.000000 or 27.865.867,00000.

Comment: Convert(char(N), floatValue, code) where code is one of 0,1,2 gives some limited control over display formatting. More detail here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
convert(varchar,cast(sum(NoInvoAb * CstPr) as money),-1)
```

Eg:

```
declare @aa int

set @aa =123123123
Select convert(varchar,cast(@aa as money),-1) as ColumnName
```

Output:

```
123,123,123.00
```

Comment: it just gives me 191143487,00 as answer, i want 191 143 487.00, eg some space or dot between numbers so i can read easy

Comment: I have edited answer above and displayed the output out of convert(varchar,cast(sum(NoInvoAb * CstPr) as money),-1). I think this is more readable.